# Auto Remove of Empty Span Class When Added Beside Input Type Text in Wordress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having a problem in my wordpress header adding search button.

I figured out that when I added input type text beside an empty span class, the span class search icon removes after refreshing the page. Any idea how can I fix this?

Here's my code

```
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url('../wp-content/plugins/search-extend/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot? 
#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../wp-content/plugins/search-extend/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.ttf') 
format('truetype');
}

.sb-icon-search {
color: #fff;
background: #00c80e;
z-index: 90;
font-size: 22px;
font-family: 'icomoon';
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 }

.sb-icon-search:before
 {
content: "\e000";
 }
 </style>

 <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
   <form>
     <input class="sb-search-submit" type="text" value="">          
     <span class="sb-icon-search"></span> #This removes automatically after 
   refreshing the page
   </form>
 </div>
```

I already tried this function

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
$opts = '*[id|name|class|style]';
$initArray['valid_elements'] .= ',' . $opts;
$initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $opts;
return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

But it seems that the issue is not from the Text editor since i tried changing
the input type "text" to type "submit" it works fine. All removed even I inspect it.
Any Idea please? Please Help.

Comment: Is it still in the DOM? or its removed from it when you inspect it?

Comment: Still removed even I inspect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the editor is removing it.

I think you can add the search directly to the sb-search item instead of the icon. I have added the css code which will help you. You might have to adjust the position.

```css
.sb-search {
  position: relative;
  /* other css properties */
}

.sb-search:before {
  content: "\e000";
  color: #fff;
  background: #00c80e;
  z-index: 90;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  /* You might have to adjust the position */
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about the span element and you can remove it.